# How to obtain mail icon on the top panel?

Tags: unity, 13.04, notification, gmail

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04. In 12.04 I used gmail notifier and I had handy mail icon on the top panel.

Now with 13.04 I tried few email notifiers (like gm-notifier or unity mail) and I always ended up without mail icon on the top panel... Also, notification seems to not work.. even though I configured them and I have indicator-messages app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have Unitymail running on 13.04 with it's appindicator. To enable some indicators you need a package named sni-qt installed. You find it in the USC.

Comment: got this already...

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry I can't help. If you use a gmail-account, you can alternatively set it up in the Ubuntu Online Accounts, in which case it would integrate in the default messages indicator.

Answer (score 0):

The mail indicator in the top panel won't be visible if no programs are using it. To see whether you have any programs using the mail indicator you'll need to use *dconf-editor*. If you don't have it installed, you'll need to install it first by opening the terminal and typing

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

After which you can run it by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `dconf-editor`.

When it's open, you'll have to find the messages indicator. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, so on my system it's in *com.canonical.indicator.messages*. If it's empty, you can then manually add programs to it, like ['thunderbird.desktop','unity-mail.desktop'], etc.

Make sure to restart the unity panel after you're done by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing

```
restart unity-panel-service
```

The mail icon should then appear on the top panel.

However, I've just tried installing Unity Mail myself, and the notifications don't work, neither on the top panel nor on the dashboard on the left. This appears to be due to an unsolved [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-mail/+bug/1309566) within the program.

Good luck, and let me know if you find a program that works!